# Equalizer columns inside Accordion

Tags: zurb-foundation, accordion, equalizer

I am new to Foundation. I am currently stucked at having Equalizer columns inside Accordion.

What happened is that, Accordion did not create enough room for contents inside, making it looks as if the contents flow out of its panel. After few attempts I realized that "data-equalizer" and "data-equalizer-watch" are the culprit here. Once I remove it everything works fine. However I really hope to remain Equalizer inside Accordion.

http://rubyss.com/i/cleanpro2

Sorry for my poor command of English. Please click on the Category Type 2 & Type 3 in Photos section to see what I am talking about.

Thanks for y'all.

```
<dl class="accordion" id="gallery-list" data-accordion>
                <dd>
                    <a class="title" href="#panel1">Category Type 1</a>
                    <div id="panel1" class="content active">                        
                        <div class="row" data-equalizer>
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: pink" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2014</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 05</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: pink" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2013</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: pink" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2012</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd>
                    <a class="title" href="#panel2">Category Type 2</a>
                    <div id="panel2" class="content">
                        <div class="row" data-equalizer>
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: #cccccc" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2014</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 05</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: #cccccc" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2013</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: #cccccc" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2012</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <dd>
                    <a class="title" href="#panel3">Category Type 3</a>
                    <div id="panel3" class="content">
                        <div class="row" data-equalizer>
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: #dddddd" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2014</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 05</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel" style="background: #dddddd" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2013</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel4" style="background: #dddddd" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <h3 class="blue title">2012</h3>
                                <ul class="gallery-list">
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 01</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 02</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 03</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Photo Album 04</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </dd>
            </dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

foundation equalizer works only on `:visible` elements, 
all that you keep inside closed accordion rows is not `:visible`, so it's not processed.

You have to launch again equalizer after opening a `<dd>` row with this statment:

```
Foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow();
```

Actually (version 5.2.2) accordion does not have any callback function for open event,
so just go in foundation.accordion.js file and trigger a custom event at the end of  `.on('click.fndtn.accordion'...` function, like this:

```
accordion.trigger('accordion-toggled');
```

Below the modified foundation.accordion.js event method (line 19 in 5.2.2 version)
with the event trigger

```
events : function () {
  var self = this;
  var S = this.S;
  S(this.scope)
  .off('.fndtn.accordion')
  .on('click.fndtn.accordion', '[' + this.attr_name() + '] dd > a', function (e) {
    var accordion = S(this).closest('[' + self.attr_name() + ']'),
        target = S('#' + this.href.split('#')[1]),
        siblings = S('dd > .content', accordion),
        aunts = $('dd', accordion),
        settings = accordion.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init'),
        active_content = S('dd > .content.' + settings.active_class, accordion),
        active_parent = S('dd.' + settings.active_class, accordion);
    e.preventDefault();

    if (! S(this).closest('dl').is(accordion)) { return; }

    if (settings.toggleable && target.is(active_content)) {
      active_parent.toggleClass(settings.active_class, false);
      return target.toggleClass(settings.active_class, false);
    }

    if (!settings.multi_expand) {
      siblings.removeClass(settings.active_class);
      aunts.removeClass(settings.active_class);
    }

    target.addClass(settings.active_class).parent().addClass(settings.active_class);
    accordion.trigger('accordion-toggled'); //add this line
  });
}
```

Then, put a listener in your js, so you keep your events handler outside the foundation js:

```
$(document).on( "accordion-toggled", function({   
    Foundation.libs.equalizer.reflow();
});
```

Comment: Just perfect thank you so much !!!
By the way, Foundation now have callbacks on accordion :)
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html#callbacks
So it's even more simple !

Comment: Yeah, foundation js is under development: they released 3 new version of this library in the last 3 months, i based my answer on 5.2.2 but i think that they will make these utilities more versatile